# dein package manager not installing plugins

Tags: packages

I'm very confused by the documentation in dein. It says:

```
dein#add({repo}[, {options}])
        Initialize a plugin.
        {repo} is the repository URI or local repository directory
        path.  If {repo} starts with github user name (ex:
        "Shougo/dein.vim"), dein will install github plugins.
        See |dein-options| for what to set in {options}.
        Note: You must call it in |dein#begin()| block.
```

So it sounds to me like I can just drop in `call dein#add('dense-analysis/ale')` and the plugin will be installed.

But the `dense-analysis/ale` plugin I want to use never gets installed and downloaded. I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
if dein#load_state('~/git_repos/dein')
  call dein#begin('~/git_repos/dein')

  " load plugins
    call dein#add('~/git_repos/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim')
    call dein#add('dense-analysis/ale')
    if !has('nvim')
      call dein#add('roxma/nvim-yarp')
      call dein#add('roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc')
    endif

  call dein#end()
  call dein#save_state()
endif
```

Comment: Did you run `:call dein#install()` after opening Vim with this vimrc?

Comment: No, but the documentation doesn't say anything about doing that. That's what I'm trying to get clarification on. The documentation says dein#add is all you need to do. So I don't know if I have something misconfigured or what.

Comment: See step 3 here: https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend using vim-plug as a plug-in manager. It has same performance features of dein, but it has commands and an "UI" which makes it easier and more obvious to use. You're also more likely to find instructions on how to install specific plug-ins on vim-plug (rarely I see instructions for dein). And if instructions are available for Vundle only, it's trivial to adapt them for vim-plug (just use `Plug` instead of the Vundle command.)

Comment: Yeah, I have used Plug in the past before I really knew what I was doing. Then I went to pathogen. Then I tried the new vim8 plugin manager. Now I'm trying dein. I may go back to Plug now as I know what lazy loading is. Thanks. The vim ecosystem is insane.

Comment: Yeah I saw your other posts on trying to load plug-ins conditionally... My first advice there is: don't worry about that! Most plug-ins use ftplugin or autoload which means their code only loads when actually used (so they won't delay your startup.) And if you do need to load some conditionally, vim-plug has `'for'` and `'on'` features to configure that correctly and load them only when needed...

Comment: Well, I've got an insane amount of plugins. I recently started playing with rails/ruby and there was a full 1 or 2 second delay before the file loaded. Probably a bad config on my part. But I decided that I'm going to retool everything to try to steamline things as efficiently as I can.

Comment: The problem is optimizing without knowing where the bottleneck really is... Then you're just doing random changes and hoping one of them works. See `:help slow-start` and `:help profiling` to help you understand where the problem really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the "install" function after you open Vim with the vimrc including the dein configuration:

```
:call dein#install()
```

See step 3 in the ["Quick Start"](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start) part of dein's README:

> 3. Open vim and install dein
>
> ```
> :call dein#install()
> ```

Comment: OK, I think the documentation definitely needs some work, then. Because it clearly says the #add function will "install github plugins."

Comment: The section of the README addresses how to install the dein plugin, not other plugins.

Comment: @StevieD See above... My recommendation is to use vim-plug instead. It's fully featured yet easy to use.

Comment: @StevieD Yeah even that part is ambiguous, looking at the source code it's clear that `dein#install()` will install the plug-ins too. In fact, you can pass it an optional argument with a list of plug-ins to install (in case you want to install a subset only.)